# 14.04 Wifi disconnects every 10 seconds or so

Tags: wireless, 14.04

When ever I use my home wifi on my laptop's internal wireless card, it disconnects every 10 or 20 seconds and presents the window to enter the password again. It is fine when I use a hard wired connection, different network or if I use a different device (e.g. android phone).

Any idea what's causing this or how I could stop it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Uks2

Comment: Do you know the make and model of the wireless card ? If not open terminal and type  sudo lshw  and add the results (just copy paste) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it might help it might not.

Open dash, find network connections (not just network), highlight your connection and choose forget then close the window, now open the one just called network, with the orange folder icon (there are two) and choose your connection from the list, click the little arrow next to it and this will allow you to manually configure your network.

Make sure you check your password and use the correct formatting eg upper and lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/646476/146769) answer solves the problem. Me too was facing almost same problem. Mine got fixed by

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

You can also update the driver as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/645472/146769), if it is required.