# wifi disconnecting within few min in ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek-wireless

Good evening, i am using a ubuntu 14.04 lts version on my laptop,
whenever i connect to a wifi network, it disconnects automatically after 5-10 min, I have tried most of the posted solutions online as the prob seems common, however im a new user of ubuntu and do not have much experience with the terminal.
I tried reinstalling the entire OS but the problem persists.
my laptop config, is 
HP probook 440 g2,
4 gb ram, 500 gb hardrive,
intel hd 5500 graphics processor 
ubuntu linux 14.04 LTS 64 bit system.

kindly help me out as the hardware support from hp has ruled out any defect in my wireless card and i do not wish to switch over to windows.
my system shows wifi is working but it just would not connect again till i reboot the OS.
NO supplied link so far has been able to fix this problem on a permanent basis.
regards.

`bhagirath@bhagirath-HP-ProBook-440-G2:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: i just edited an posted my output in my request ... please find.

Comment: I had that problem with a similar card but the updates fixed it. have you ran `sudo apt-get udpate` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Realtek 8723BE Wifi problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635625/realtek-8723be-wifi-problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install a driver this way.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

it should work better after reboot.

Comment: Ok. i will check and come back :)

Comment: This is ppa for Realtek drivers from Larry Finger's github.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpamo8q3bw/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpamo8q3bw/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 2F22E44A from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpamo8q3bw/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 2F22E44A: public key "Launchpad PPA for Pilot6" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK

Comment: @BhagirathTallapragada Please do not post extended outputs to comments. This looks OK. If there are no errors, then run all the rest commands and reboot.

Comment: Thank you .. after a few hours of continuous downloads .. i can say my wifi is wrking properly... i would however like to understand why this problem came up in the first place.

Comment: @BhagirathTallapragada The problem was in a bad kernel driver. The driver you installed works better. It the answer was helpful, then you can accept it by clicking check sign at the left.