# Wifi is frequently disconnecting

Tags: networking, wireless, ralink, wpa2

The Wifi is frequently disconnecting in Ubuntu 15.04. My Wireless interface of Ubuntu is RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

When wifi is disconnected, on `iwconfig` I got the following

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

After each disconnection I have to restart network for reconnection by

> sudo service network-manager restart

Comment: You might need a better wifi driver. Or change kernel

Comment: @Serg The Kernel version is latest, ie 3.19.0-26-generic and I think driver too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiFi disconnects for few seconds and resume](http://askubuntu.com/questions/730908/wifi-disconnects-for-few-seconds-and-resume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if in `iwconfig` Power Management is on.

If yes `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` and see if that helps.

To keep it upon restart do `sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/wireless`

Comment: @ tikend.   Power Management was on. changed to off. Now, for past few hours wifi is not disconnecting. Thanks.

Comment: After setting the Power management Off, every thing was working fine for last few days. But now Wifi is again frequently disconnecting.

Comment: Did you checked the `iwconfig` if it's still off?

Comment: When wifi is disconnected, on ~$ iwconfig I got the following

eth0 no wireless extensions.

wlan0 IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:off/any
Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=20 dBm
Retry short limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off Power Management:off

lo no wireless extensions.