# Why did my Wifi stop working all of a sudden?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

My wifi has stopped working since yesterday. It only starts working when I disable my connection and enable it again. Then it stops working after a couple of second again.

Something is clearly really wrong with my Lenovo Laptop (Broadcom & Ubuntu), but I don't know what. All the drivers are installed and I have tried rebooting and even reinstalling ubuntu. I even installed xubuntu and linux mint but the problem is still there.

How can I fix this?

Dmesg:
http://textuploader.com/a0hgx

lspci -vnn | grep Network showed:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Check if in iwconfig Power Management is on, see this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/645835/wifi-is-frequently-disconnecting/646476#646476

Comment: @dhiya It is now set to on. I hope it helps now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check whether Power Management is on, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645835/wifi-is-frequently-disconnecting/646476#646476) answer

use

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

to restart wifi