# Unstable WiFi on desktop Ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop and now having problems with WiFi connection. After each restart it works perfectly but some time later just drops. Sometimes it restores, sometimes don't. In the beginning I was able to restart it by clicking on the WiFi connection launcher icon and reconnecting to it. But then I searched the internet and found this 2 workarounds:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

and

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
modprobe -r rtl8723be
modprobe rtl8723be
exit
```

Did both and now I just can't reconnect by clicking on icon, need to restart PC.
Found this to restart connection without rebooting:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Here is output of wireless info script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 15 Aug 2015 15:58 EEST +0300

Booted last: 15 Aug 2015 15:49 EEST +0300

Script from: 14 Jul 2015 17:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-45-generic #60~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67 and other motherboards [1043:8432]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0781:5572 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2188:0ae1  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8192cu              67741  0 
rtl_usb                18448  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                64255  2 rtl_usb,rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        53172  1 rtl8192cu
mac80211              652777  3 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              498458  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
eeepc_wmi              13151  0 
asus_wmi               24094  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
video                  20128  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    19193  1 asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'wlan0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6127 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5181 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4296934 (4.2 MB)  TX bytes:785909 (785.9 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"krasota"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'krasota' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=150 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:5   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       862     1  0 15:49 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [krasota] -----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192cu
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           150 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    Keenetic-0134:   Infra, <MAC 'Keenetic-0134' [AC2]>, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 87 WPA2
    Soti:            Infra, <MAC 'Soti' [AC4]>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA WPA2
    nexus:           Infra, <MAC 'nexus' [AC3]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 20 WPA WPA2
    RAMSA:           Infra, <MAC 'RAMSA' [AN4]>, Freq 2432 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 4 WPA2
    Lanet:           Infra, <MAC 'Lanet' [AN5]>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 4 WPA WPA2
    volia 30 2:      Infra, <MAC 'volia 30 2' [AN6]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 4 WEP
    mimimishka:      Infra, <MAC 'mimimishka' [AN7]>, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 4 WPA2
    EVA BRAUN:       Infra, <MAC 'EVA BRAUN' [AN8]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 4 WPA2
    *krasota:        Infra, <MAC 'krasota' [AC1]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA WPA2
    putinKHUYLO:     Infra, <MAC 'putinKHUYLO' [AN10]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 4 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.102
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/mimimishka]] (600 root)
[connection] id=mimimishka | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=mimimishka | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/krasota]] (600 root)
[connection] id=krasota | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=krasota | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Kiev (based on set time zone)

country UA:
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), NO-OUTDOOR
    (5150 - 5350 @ 40), (N/A, 20), NO-OUTDOOR
    (57240 - 65880 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), NO-OUTDOOR

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'krasota' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"krasota"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000002b8d0fe19
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Keenetic-0134' [AC2]>
                    Channel:3
                    Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Keenetic-0134"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000649a2dad2ce
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'nexus' [AC3]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=12/70  Signal level=-98 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"nexus"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001a689e7a006
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'Soti' [AC4]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Soti"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000185dbcfac
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8192cu]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_A.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n USB wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
srcversion:     93FD064658D2AD5B6991075
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8192c-common,rtl_usb,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C1:A3:1E:DB:9F:C4:C6:4E:2D:95:A7:FF:18:A6:73:D1:8C:AB:15:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[rtl_usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_usb.ko
description:    USB basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     94CFED30E3318E18EC4B740
depends:        rtlwifi,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C1:A3:1E:DB:9F:C4:C6:4E:2D:95:A7:FF:18:A6:73:D1:8C:AB:15:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     8362106E96F806A9DBAE565
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C1:A3:1E:DB:9F:C4:C6:4E:2D:95:A7:FF:18:A6:73:D1:8C:AB:15:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtl8192c_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     A279C50E29ED7F277EAF738
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C1:A3:1E:DB:9F:C4:C6:4E:2D:95:A7:FF:18:A6:73:D1:8C:AB:15:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     315DCE1E2614AE1F38132D3
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C1:A3:1E:DB:9F:C4:C6:4E:2D:95:A7:FF:18:A6:73:D1:8C:AB:15:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-45-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D48679749A6B8B822E391CA
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-45-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        C1:A3:1E:DB:9F:C4:C6:4E:2D:95:A7:FF:18:A6:73:D1:8C:AB:15:A6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8192cu]
debug: 0
swenc: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf]
options rtl8723be fwlps=0

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   20.635259] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   20.668023] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   21.081076] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   22.700664] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'mimimishka' [AN7]>
[   22.724773] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'mimimishka' [AN7]> (try 1/3)
[   22.726614] wlan0: authenticated
[   22.728123] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'mimimishka' [AN7]> (try 1/3)
[   22.740820] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'mimimishka' [AN7]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   22.740880] wlan0: associated
[   22.740888] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   27.074978] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC 'mimimishka' [AN7]> (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
[   27.094197] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'mimimishka' [AN7]>
[   27.106253] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'mimimishka' [AN7]> (try 1/3)
[   27.107837] wlan0: authenticated
[   27.109691] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'mimimishka' [AN7]> (try 1/3)
[   27.123577] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'mimimishka' [AN7]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   27.123643] wlan0: associated
[   31.274826] wlan0: deauthenticated from <MAC 'mimimishka' [AN7]> (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
[   38.238369] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'krasota' [AC1]>
[   38.250536] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'krasota' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   38.253479] wlan0: authenticated
[   38.255457] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'krasota' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   38.274106] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'krasota' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[   38.274165] wlan0: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Please help.

Comment: This question is related http://askubuntu.com/questions/645835/wifi-is-frequently-disconnecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything wrong. You tried to configure drivers not related to your wireless adapter at all.

You need to install the correct driver this way.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms linux-firmware
```

If you did not spoil anything else, your USB dongle should work better after **reboot**.

It also makes sense to remove the configuration files you've created by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Comment: wasd@notebook:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipousptlot/rtlwifi

Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:hanipousptlot/rtlwifi'.

Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.

Comment: Sorry for that. Fixed a typo in my username.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Installed, don't know yet is it working. After last network-manager restart there was no connection interruption.

Comment: Test it for some time. This driver is reliable enough. When you are sure that the solution was helpful, please accept the answer by clicking the check sign at the left.

Comment: Everything works perfectly + now I get better wifi signal. Thank you alot!